# getBoundingClientRect() for element overflowing the container

Tags: javascript, getboundingclientrect

Suppose we have a text overflowing its container div:

```js
console.log(document.querySelector("p").getBoundingClientRect().width)
```

```css
#myDiv {
  width: 20px;
  background-color: wheat;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}
```

```html
<div id="myDiv">
  <p>foobarfoobarfoobarfoobarfoobar</p>
</div>
```

As you can see the container div has a fixed width (20px) but even if the text is obviously bigger than that `getBoundingClientRect()` doesn't go over that container value.

Is there any alternative for getting the bounding rectangle of the text element in this situation?

Comment: But this value is correct. If you put another `<div>foo bar</div>` after your original `<div>`, then set `div { display: inline-block; }`, you’ll see that both `<div>`s will overlap, because the actual rectangle only occupies a width of `20px`, even if there’s additional rendering going on beyond this boundary. What do you need this for, anyway?

Comment: @user4642212 *"What do you need this for, anyway?"* I need to compute the text length in a page which HTML/CSS I cannot modify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting `display: inline-block;` on the `p` element so that it has a specific width:

```js
console.log(document.querySelector("p").getBoundingClientRect().width)
```

```css
#myDiv {
  width: 20px;
  background-color: wheat;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}

p {
   display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="myDiv">
 <p>foobarfoobarfoobarfoobarfoobar</p>
</div>
```